# Accessing SIM Toolkit in Android settings spawns duplicate SIM card entries?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, sim-card, dual-sim

I have OnePlus 2, rooted and has Xposed Framework. I don't recall ever visiting the SIM Toolkit menu before. But I tried it today and this happened:

[image: Duplicate SIM entries]

Settings -> Wireless Settings -> Sim & Network Settings -> Click on a SIM (SIM 1 or SIM 2, this one is dual-SIM) -> Scroll to the bottom of the list and click on **SIM Toolkit**.

This opens up an empty SIM Toolkit menu (which seems to stay empty no matter how long you leave it (tried several minutes)), and when you go back out of it, you see a couple of new SIM entries have appeared in the list of the current SIM's menu. They each have a checkbox slider thing next to them, but if you tick one slider, in a second all of them will get ticked.

I realised SIM Toolkit is an app. I can force-close it, but I can't seem to be able to clear its data or cache. I managed to freeze it, rebooted, but the existing SIM duplicates are not gone.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to proceed with fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out exactly what was misbehaving and why, but I accidentally now (years later) found out how to force a refresh: I put the phone in flight mode, opened the sim tray, swapped the sims, put it back in and disabled airplane mode. This cleared all the duplicates.